# Can turicreate python library be installed on raspberry pi?

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-os, pip

Recently I am trying to install `turicreate` library on my Rraspberry Pi 3 model B+ by following all the required steps to be done for installation for operating systems like Ubuntu which is similar to Raspberry Pi OS that I am running. After executing the command `sudo python3 -m pip install turicreate`, I have to observe the following error command:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting turicreate
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/7e/796c23c3468cb9eab660359825f3a330343f6d3f6e471d781a4c59a0b3ff/turicreate-6.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: turicreate
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for turicreate ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-0ppwy1di/turicreate/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-cn6ofcmb --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  installing to build/bdist.linux-armv7l/wheel
  running install
  
  
  
          ==================================================================================
          TURICREATE ERROR
  
          If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
          for your system.
  
          Supported Platforms:
              * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
              * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
  
          Support Python Versions:
              * 2.7
              * 3.5
              * 3.6
              * 3.7
              * 3.8
  
          Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
              `pip install -U pip`
  
          ==================================================================================
  
  
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for turicreate
  Running setup.py clean for turicreate
Failed to build turicreate
Installing collected packages: turicreate
  Running setup.py install for turicreate ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-0ppwy1di/turicreate/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fqyewkw1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    
    
    
            ==================================================================================
            TURICREATE ERROR
    
            If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
            for your system.
    
            Supported Platforms:
                * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
                * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
    
            Support Python Versions:
                * 2.7
                * 3.5
                * 3.6
                * 3.7
                * 3.8
    
            Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
                `pip install -U pip`
    
            ==================================================================================
    
    
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-0ppwy1di/turicreate/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fqyewkw1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-0ppwy1di/turicreate/
```

My question is, how to solve this problem? In which area I am doing wrong? Can anyone please explain? Or is `turicreate` library not supported on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Supported Platforms:
            * **macOS 10.12+ x86_64**.
            * Linux **x86_64** (including WSL on Windows 10). might give a hint.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like this is only available for x86 architecture and 64 bit OS's. Pi is arm architecture and the default is 32 bit. You may be able to build this package from source.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments you cannot install the turicreate library on a Raspberry Pi. The error message returned:

```
Supported Platforms:
    * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
    * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
```

These are only operating systems compiled for the intel x86 processor or compatible AMD processors. But a Raspberry Pi uses a different ARM processor that cannot run programs for x86. You have to find the library compiled for the ARM processor or you compile it by yourself from the sources on a Raspberry Pi.